# Why does a moving image leave duplicates of its self when stopping and starting too quickly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
def function():

    import pygame

    pygame.init()

    blue = 0,255,255
    red = 255,0,0
    white = 255,255,255

    Location = 136
    Level = 432

    SKY = 0

    space1 = 200
    space1 = 200

    WaterLevel = 452

    Left_Rect = pygame.Rect(0,452,135,100)
    Right_Rect = pygame.Rect(137,452,135,100)

    CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 30

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((272,552))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Boat Game')

    boat = pygame.image.load("FinalBoat.png").convert_alpha()
    boat = pygame.transform.scale(boat, (40,25))

    stop = False

    is_Left = False
    is_Right = False

    while not stop:


####### Background ###############################################

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,(0,SKY,272,552))

        SKY -= 1

####### Controles #################################################

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, Left_Rect)

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, Right_Rect)

####### Boat #################################################

        gameDisplay.blit(boat, (Location, Level))

####### Water ################################################

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,blue,(0,WaterLevel,272,100))

####### Movement ##############################################


        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            print event

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                is_Left = Left_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                is_Right = Right_Rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                is_Left = False
                is_Right = False

            if Location == 0:
                is_Left = False

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if is_Left:
            Location -= 5

        elif is_Right:
            Location += 5

        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()

function()
```

It is hard to explain but I have a game where an image of a boat move horizontally across the screen, and controlled by clicking on the rectangles in the bottom corners. When I stop and start too quickly or change directions too abruptly the image duplicates itself in a trail across the screen. The trail does not disappear. I hope someone can explain this odd anomaly.

Answer (score 1):

The trail appears, because the screen should clear every frame. You are doing so by drawing the white background. But in your code is the line `SKY -= 1` which moves the white rectangle up and now there is a gap between the cyan button area and the sky which will be not cleared every frame. Now when the boat moves the picture of the move from the frame before will not clear.

**Edit:** I'm not familiar with pygame but there are two `pygame.display.update()`, I think you need only one.

Comment: Thanks, but the the same thing happened

Comment: Too bad, I deleted the `SKY -= 1` and seemed like it worked as it should. Now I can't reproduce any problem. Sorry.